# Why is screen is terminating without root?

Tags: permissions, gnu-screen

I have installed screen on Fedora 19. When I test the command as root remotely through SSH, it works perfectly. For instance, if I enter `screen` a new terminal emulator is started and waits for commands. I can detach it, etc. However when I try to do the same once I am logged remotely through SSH as a standard user, the command terminates immediately. The only message I see is `[screen is terminating]`.

Does someone have already had this problem? Is it related to bad permissions?

**Update:**

```
$ strace -e trace=file screen
execve("/usr/bin/screen", ["screen"], [/* 23 vars */]) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libutempter.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libpam.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libfreebl3.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libaudit.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/UTF-8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/steam/.nethackrc", F_OK)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
readlink("/proc/self/fd/0", "/dev/pts/0", 4095) = 10
stat("/dev/pts/0", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
lstat("/dev/pts/0", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
open("/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/shadow", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
readlink("/proc/self/fd/0", "/dev/pts/0", 4095) = 10
stat("/dev/pts/0", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
stat("/dev/pts/0", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
lstat("/dev/pts/0", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
stat("/var/run/screen", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=60, ...}) = 0
Directory '/var/run/screen' must have mode 777.
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

I have tried to change permissions to 777 but then when I execute `screen`, I get:

> Directory '/var/run/screen' must have mode 775.

Therefore, I have reverted my changes.

Comment: What is the command?

Comment: The simplest one: "screen". I recorded an example at http://shelr.tv/records/525179c7966080791000005f

Comment: Are you on a VPS or hosted server, by chance?

Comment: It is an hosted server

Comment: `strace -e trace=file screen` to check if it fails on file access. Or uses `tmux`as a work-around, its works the same except it uses ^b instead of ^a.

Comment: I have updated my question for the strace output. I have also tried  tmux but when I execute the command I get on the terminal the characters `1;2c`.

Comment: I have *exactly* the same issue, including the one with tmux, but it's almost 2 years later... Did you solve?

Answer (score 8):

The flip-flopping between "must have mode 777" and "must have mode 775" is caused by `strace`.

`screen` is usually a setuid or setgid program. It gains extra privileges when it is executed, which is uses to create socket files and/or modify utmp.

When a process is being traced, setuid and setgid are disabled. The tracing process, controlled by the less-privileged user, can take over the traced process so it must run without its extra privileges to avoid giving the original user too much power.

`screen` detects whether it is being run with setuid privileges, setgid privileges, or neither, and adjusts its expectation of the directory permissions accordingly.

So this creates a class of problems that can't be easily debugged with `strace`.

But if you're root, there is a workaround! If the tracing process is running as root, then the traced process can gain privileges normally. So here's what you do:

1. Open 2 new terminals
2. In the first terminal, log in to the remote machine as root
3. In the second terminal, log in to the remote machine as normal user
4. Use `ps` to get the PID of the normal user's shell process in the second terminal
5. In the first terminal, run `strace -f -p SHELLPID`
6. In the second terminal, run screen and watch it fail
7. In the first terminal, you now have the strace log you need to find out what's really wrong.

The key addition to the `strace` command is the `-f` option, which tells it to trace child processes. You need it to trace the screen that will be a child of the shell process you specified with `-p`.

I also like to use `-ff` and specify an output file with `-o`, as in

```
strace -ff -o /tmp/screentrace -p SHELLPID
```

which will create a separate output file for each child process. Afterward you read them with `less /tmp/screentrace*` and the result is usually cleaner than what you get using a single `-f`.

**UPDATE**

Now that I've seen the strace output, I don't know exactly what went wrong, but this line is the most surprising thing in the trace:

```
chown("/dev/pts/2", 1002, 5)            = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

A few lines earlier, it created a pty, which was revealed by `TIOCGPTN` to be number 2.

```
open("/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR)               = 5
...
ioctl(5, TIOCGPTN, [2])                 = 0
stat("/dev/pts/2", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
```

But it was unable to chown it. I don't know why that chown would fail, but the chown failure does give a plausible reason why screen gave up. You can get a little more information by adding `-v` to the strace options, and looking at the `stat` after the `TIOCGPTN` to see who owns the `/dev/pts/` entry.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed procedure. I have tried to look at the output generated by strace but I cannot figure out what is wrong. Hereafter is the link with the content of the three files generated by strace: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aeqDwTBX any idea is welcomed :)

Answer (score 5):

**Ensure no other `screen` is using that device**

This can be achieved with https://superuser.com/questions/97844/how-can-i-determine-what-process-has-a-file-open-in-linux :

```
sudo lsof /dev/ttyS0
```

And then kill that process if that is the case.

For some reason, under this condition, `sudo screen` can still access the device, but then that connection will miss characters, which are consumed by the other `screen`.

A common case where this happens is if you detached from `screen` with Ctrl + A D, leaving it running on the background, rather than killing it with Ctrl + A K.

**Ensure the user has read and write permission to the file**

E.g. on Ubuntu you want to add the user to the `dialout` group: https://askubuntu.com/a/133244/52975

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

Comment: As an alternative, `sudo adduser $USER dialout` does the same as your `usermod` command

Answer (score 3):

When I encountered this error message.  I had to adjust my permissions with the following:

`chmod 2775 /usr/bin/screen`

And this resolved the issue for me.  The 2 is very important for the correct access permissions.

You should read up more on SUID, SGID, Sticky Bit, ACL's and how they impact access.

Comment: u+s works. It's not nice but I can't see other solutions at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

On of possible reasons for that bug - incorrect selinux policies, but according to redhat bugtracker such errors were fixed in fedora 17/18.

As workaround you can change variable `SCREENDIR` in you `~/.bashrc` to something like `$HOME/.screen`.

Comment: I have tried but it does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Screen command was already running. So I terminated it and retyped the command.
Yes this is not a pretty good resolution like others but it takes less time to do this.

Just ps and find the pid, kill PID and go ahead with retyping screen command again.

If you are running multiple screen commands, make sure you terminate the correct process associated with your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue resolved after commenting the following line in /etc/fstab and rebooting:

```
devpts         /dev/pts        devpts  defaults        0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same issue and a pretty similar strace output.

This fixed it:

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/screen
sudo chmod 755 /var/run/screen
```

credits: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/screen-terminates-immediately-4175444530/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just logout from current session and relogin, and the screen works again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different issue, but I figured it could be useful to someone landing here just because of the title:

I noticed that when I exit `screen` with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>a</kbd>   <kbd>d</kbd>  (detach), the process is not terminated and if I try to start another session I get  the `[screen is terminating]` error. Starting with `sudo` works. Killing the process also works.

If I exit with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>   <kbd>\</kbd>  (quit), I can start another session normally without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I was running from an unprivileged user whose default shell was `/bin/false`. The fix was simply to put: `shell "/bin/bash"` in `~/.screenrc`.